# Need to use JSON.stringify ()

Tags: javascript, json

I have a return object and need to print some attributes, but some attributes the JSON.stringify not recognize.

Ex:

```
Object = {"Date":"Mon, 22 Jun 2015 10:56:50 GMT","Content-Length":"1887","Content-Type":"application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8","Server":"Apache-Coyote/1.1"}
```

1. This: `JSON.stringify(Object.Date);` // This works
2. Need: `JSON.stringify(Object.Content-Length);` // This does not work

Why 2 does not work?

Comment: Use JSON.stringify(Object['Content-Length']); .... no variable name or key can be directly called it is contains a invalid symbol.

Answer (score 1):

It fails because

```
Content-Length
```

is not a valid Object key because of the hyphen.

You can try this instead

```
Object = {"Date":"Mon, 22 Jun 2015 10:56:50 GMT","Content-Length":"1887","Content-Type":"application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8","Server":"Apache-Coyote/1.1"}
alert(JSON.stringify(Object['Content-Length']))
```

though there is no reason to do so, as you can simply get the value with

```
alert(Object['Content-Length'])
```